# Can I require that a user enable push notifications?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Naturally this is *programmatically* possible (using `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes`). This is a policy question.

Can I require that a user has push notifications enabled to be allowed to use an app, or will this behaviour cause the app to be rejected by Apple?

The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) includes a section on push notifications (§ 5), but does not cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I might not want any notification from any application because I am busy.  Therefore I turn Notifications **on** or **off** as I choose.  All you can do is display an UIAlertView reminding the user that push notification is disable when they enter your app.

Comment: Hi,how can i detect if push notification is enable or disable programatically.

Comment: `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` doesn't enable remote notification. That method returns the types of notifications the application accepts. If the applications accepts none, then you know the user has disable notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Submit and see what happens.  First, try it with the app closing itself if the user has push notifications turned off, showing them an alert letting them know why the app won't run and how to fix it (and a button that will take them to the right part of Settings if that's possible).  If Apple rejects it, then just take out the app quiting code and let them continue by dismissing the nag screen.

Like you say, there's nothing explicitly forbidding it in the guidelines that you can find, so the only way to get an answer is to submit code and see what happens, since you generally can't get a straight answer out of Apple regarding these issues until you have something specific and real for them to consider.